# Expand structure template with dynamic content

Tags: org-mode

I want to be able to expand structure template into source block with filename-of-the-current-buffer + ".py", or in general to evaluate any dynamic content

i.e.:

```
#+begin_src python :tangle current-org-filename.py

#+end_src
```

org-tempo doesn't seem to be able to do that as it keeps only static templates. Is there a way?

EDIT 1: I've solved it with yasnippet by defining following template:

```
# name: python
# key: <sj
# --
#+begin_src python :tangle ${1:`(concat (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) ".py")`}
$0
#+end_src
```

But let me know if there is better way

Comment: Are you aware that you can set the extension used for a language via `org-babel-tangle-lang-exts` (e.g. via `M-x customize-variable`)? Then when just using the value `yes` for `:tangle`, the tangled file will have the same filename-(base) as the org file. I guess for this exact use-case, this solution (i.c.w. the structured template), arguably, might be a 'better' way (or, at least, it is a good alternative).

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks!